# Как управлять атрибутами связующей таблицы?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Для максимального понимания приведу всем известный пример - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Теперь представим что в модель Appointment необходимо добавить какое-то дополнительное поле. Например, текстовое поле. Пускай это будет "описание".

У врача есть пациенты. У пациента есть врачи. И в каждом конкретном случает у каждой связи есть описание.

Добавление к врачу пациента происходит так:

```
Physician.first.patients << Patient.first
```

Это запишет все необходимые внешние ключи.

Как в дальнейшем редактировать третье поле в связующей таблице - поле "описание"?

Comment: Это смотря как устроена связующая таблица.

Comment: @D-side как в официальной документации плюс одно единственное поле - string description. В связующей таблице я это поле никак не обозначил. То есть там два `belongs_to` и все.

Comment: Первичный ключ есть в ней?

Comment: @D-side да, имеется.

Comment: Тогда можно как обычно, через класс модели. В чём именно проблема?